# How to convert XML to CSV when attributes are inside the root tag?

Tags: python, xml, csv, root

I need to convert an XML file to CSV file, in which attributes are inside the root tag.

I've checked many links but didn't find any example where XML is converted to CSV by parsing root tag's attributes.

## XML Sample:

```
<Products>
<Product ProductID="1234" ProductName="ABC" Category="Food" />
<Product ProductID="1236" ProductName="ABE" Category="Healthcare" />
</Products>
```

## Python Code (getting NoneType error):

```
ProductID = member.find('Product').attrib.get('ProductID')
Product_nodes.append(ProductID)
```

## Expected Results in CSV file:

```
ProductID, ProductName, Category
1234, ABC,Food
1236, ABE,Healthcare
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `csv` and `lxml` libraries:

```
import csv

from lxml import etree


xml_content = """<Products>
<Product ProductID="1234" ProductName="ABC" Category="Food" />
<Product ProductID="1236" ProductName="ABE" Category="Healthcare" />
</Products>"""

outfile = "products.csv"
field_names = ["ProductID", "ProductName", "Category"]
root_node = etree.fromstring(xml_content)

filehandle = open(outfile, "w", newline="")
writer = csv.DictWriter(filehandle, fieldnames=field_names)
writer.writeheader()
for node in root_node.findall("Product"):
    writer.writerow(dict(node.attrib))
filehandle.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Andreas. Unfortunately, we are using the older version of Python :(  I am getting "SyntaxError: ("'with' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6"" error. Is there any other way solving the issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How old is your Python Version, exactly? Seems like 2.5 or older?
However, this only affects the "with" block which can be simply rewritten. I will edit the answer. It might still be that the "newline" parameter in the call to open() is not working with Python 2.x (can't check it right now) or other issues arise due to encoding.

Comment: @Enric, before anything you should definitely upgrade your Python for security and efficiency reasons and compatibility with third-party modules. Even better, tell the uppers at your org: it's free to do so!

Answer (score 0):

If you've got access to XQuery or XPath 2.0+ it's simply

```
string-join(//Product/string-join((@ProductID, @ProductName, @Category),','),'&#xa;')
```